# Code style / correct structure android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

Hello fellow programmers,

I cant find a proper way to route my application, I would like one file to decide which activity has to be started

I am building an android application that in general contains:

-2 ways to start up

-3 activity's

The application can be launched by clicking the icon (standard launch)

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

And an activity is started when there is an incoming call

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
```

In the first setup there was 2 activity's one to register and one to use the application. In this
setup I added an extra activity to check if a token was present and route to the right activity.

In the setup that I have now, all the actions are in the  of a broadcast receiver. I tried implementing the logic of the extra activity.

The problem I am facing is the check of the incoming call, it is always launching the same activity CallHandler,

I think routing the application within a broadcast receiver might be bad practice, but I can not find a better way of routing the application, and the current code does not work.

Your help is very much appreciated, the following pieces of code might help explain my issue:

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver android:name=".RoutingCallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CallHandler"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >


    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CreateCallActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create_call" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

RoutingCallReceiver:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class RoutingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    TelephonyManager telephony;
    Intent in;
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PrimePhoneStateListener phoneListener = new PrimePhoneStateListener();
        telephony = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(phoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        if(telephony.getCallState()== 1){
            in = new Intent(context, CallHandler.class);
            in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(in);
        }
        else {
            TokenIO tokenHandler = new TokenIO();
            String token = tokenHandler.getToken(context);
            Log.d("AAfter", "Token");
            if(token.equals("") || token.equals(null)){
                in = new Intent(context, RegisterActivity.class);

                in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(in);
            }
            else{
                in = new Intent(context, CreateCallActivity.class);

                in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(in);
            }

        }
    }


    // when finish your job, stop listen to changes
    public void onDestroy() {
        telephony.listen(null, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "current code does not work"? The condition in `if(token.equals("") || token.equals(null))` is never true?

Comment: As mentioned the CallHandler activity is always started, so the problem is with

`if(telephony.getCallState()== 1)`

Comment: If you have incoming call ringing, that's exactly how it should be.

Comment: And if there is not an incoming call, and the application is launched manually, it starts the CallHandler activity anyways. The big question: Should I route: (1 This is fine, you can route to the right activity within 1 broadcastreceiver, (2 You cant do that, bad practice/ bad code/ not optimal you should use a main activity to route the register and createcall activities (3 there is another way ....

Answer (score 1):

you can make change in your xml file

```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
       <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <receiver android:name=".RoutingCallReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CallHandler"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >


    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CreateCallActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create_call" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

and put this tag into main activity

```
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

and i hope that will work fine.

Comment: You are suggesting that I should go back to my first setup with an extra activity just to check wich activity to launch? 

The big question I am trying to find an answer to is whether there is another way, or if the solution you provided is the one and only way.

Thank you for your time and effort

Comment: you can check which activity launch in OnRecive broadcast reciver.

Comment: Could you update your answer? If your answer gets another +1 I will mark your answer as the correct answer, but I would like another opinion before I close the question.